# Loading Geoserver WMTS layer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoserver, wmts

I am using GeoServer 2.13. I am trying to load WMTS layer into ArcGIS Desktop, but WMTS layer is not loading into it. When I am trying to load into QGIS, its loading successfully. WMTS URL is below

[http://localhost/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?](http://localhost/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?request=getcapabilities)

I also checked the User access log, ArcGIS requested URL is different than QGIS requested URL.

**ArcGIS request log:**

> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [21/Jul/2018:13:18:37 +0530] "GET
>   /geoserver/gwc/rest/wmts/nurc:Pk50095/raster/EPSG:4326/EPSG:4326:13/1965/8789?format=image/jpeg
>   HTTP/1.1" 401 1253 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [21/Jul/2018:13:18:37 +0530]
>   "GET
>   /geoserver/gwc/rest/wmts/nurc:Pk50095/raster/EPSG:4326/EPSG:4326:13/1964/8788?format=image/jpeg
>   HTTP/1.1" 401 1254 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [21/Jul/2018:13:18:37 +0530]
>   "GET
>   /geoserver/gwc/rest/wmts/nurc:Pk50095/raster/EPSG:4326/EPSG:4326:13/1964/8789?format=image/jpeg
>   HTTP/1.1" 401 1254 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [21/Jul/2018:13:18:41 +0530]
>   "GET
>   /geoserver/gwc/rest/wmts/nurc:Pk50095/raster/EPSG:4326/EPSG:4326:13/1967/8789?format=image/jpeg
>   HTTP/1.1" 401 1171

**Qgis request log:**

> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [21/Jul/2018:13:30:11 +0530] "GET
>   /geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=nurc:Pk50095&STYLE=raster&FORMAT=image/jpeg&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4326&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4326:12&TILEROW=983&TILECOL=4391
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 926 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [21/Jul/2018:13:30:11 +0530]
>   "GET
>   /geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=nurc:Pk50095&STYLE=raster&FORMAT=image/jpeg&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4326&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4326:12&TILEROW=984&TILECOL=4397
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 7429 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [21/Jul/2018:13:30:11 +0530]
>   "GET
>   /geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=nurc:Pk50095&STYLE=raster&FORMAT=image/jpeg&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4326&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4326:12&TILEROW=982&TILECOL=4398
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 7281

Can anyone suggest me how to load WMTS layer into ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: The service URL to give to ArcGIS should be without parameters, so only http://localhost/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?

Comment: @nmtoken Are you able to access GeoServer WMTS layer into ArcGIS Desktop using this URL?

Comment: Well, using a URL like http://localhost/gs213/gwc/service/wmts? in the Add WMTS Server dialogue of ArcMap (10.3.1) works for me, in that ArcMap is able to create a WMTS GetCapabilities (GC) request and parse the response to give a list of layers. If I do the same for QGIS, I get an error because QGIS makes a WMS request!  QGIS needs the full GC request with parameters, or a static capabilities document. The GeoServer GC response gives a `ServiceMetadataURL` URL for a static capabilities document pointing to something like `...rest/wmts/WMTSCapabilities.xml"/>`

Comment: If you look at the GeoServer GC response you will see that the `ResourceURL` for a layer is specified with a template like `<ResourceURL format="image/jpeg" resourceType="tile" template="http://localhost/gs213/inspire-wg/gwc/rest/wmts/UKCoShelf_BGS_1M_SBS/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}?format=image/jpeg"/>`. ArcMap is doing it's best trying to follow the info that the service has given it, when it requests, `http://localhost/gs213/inspire-wg/gwc/rest/wmts/UKCoShelf_BGS_1M_SBS/raster/EPSG:4326/EPSG:4326:0/0/1?format=image/jpeg` the issue is the resource doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Arcmap is not making a key value pair (kvp) request of the sort that geoserver expects. So it would seem not to be parsing (or following) the capabilities file.

```
<ows:Operation name="GetTile">
  <ows:DCP>
    <ows:HTTP>
      <ows:Get xlink:href="http://localhost:9080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?">
        <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
          <ows:AllowedValues>
            <ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
          </ows:AllowedValues>
        </ows:Constraint>
      </ows:Get>
    </ows:HTTP>
  </ows:DCP>
</ows:Operation>
```

So having advertised that it won't accept REST style requests GeoServer really shouldn't then advertise them under the layers (But I need to check the spec to be sure):

```
      <ResourceURL format="image/png" resourceType="tile" template="http://localhost:9080/geoserver/gwc/rest/wmts/topp:states/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}?format=image/png"/>
      <ResourceURL format="image/jpeg" resourceType="tile" template="http://localhost:9080/geoserver/gwc/rest/wmts/topp:states/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}?format=image/jpeg"/>
      <ResourceURL format="text/plain" resourceType="FeatureInfo" template="http://localhost:9080/geoserver/gwc/rest/wmts/topp:states/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}/{J}/{I}?format=text/plain"/>
```

However when I try

http://localhost:9080/geoserver/gwc/rest/wmts/topp:states/population/EPSG:4326/EPSG:4326:0/0/0?format=image/png

it does return an image so it should work in ArcMap.

It is possible that you can force kvp instead of rest in the gui somewhere, or it maybe that you will need to purchase an additional plugin to use interoperable services.

Comment: I tried to implement your valuable answer. I also tried with external geowebcache but still, I am facing the same problem. can you share me any link or document to implement "force kvp instead of rest in the GUI"?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much about arcmap

Comment: The issue is more that the GetCapabilities response gives URL template that isn't honoured

Comment: I started editing this, but it probably would have looked like vandalism so I reverted.  One issue here is that REST does not have a URL style, (it's a common misconception); REST is driven by hypermedia, the client parses the hypermedia and discovers the links it needs to follow to get the resource, it doesn't create them...  I would say that the GC advertises that only KVP is supported, (rather than REST not) and the ResourceURL does indeed give a URL template including a KVP i.e. ...`format=text/plain` so it isn't advertising something it doesn't support.

Comment: I don't use GeoServer (or indeed ArcMap) that often so I may indeed have configured something incorrectly, but as per my comment to the question, if I do a GC request to my WMTS service (running 2.13.2) the response gives me a URL that doesn't exist (http://localhost/gs213/gwc/rest/wmts/WMTSCapabilities.xml)  and similarly the (KVP) tile request I gave points to a resource that doesn't exist,  That's nothing to do with ArcMap.

Comment: sounds like a proxy config error

Comment: Don't think it's a proxy error as localhost:8080/gs213/gwc/rest/wmts/WMTSCapabilities.xml also doesn't exist.  http://localhost:8080/gs213/gwc/rest/ (and localhost:80/...) gives a page that shows a 'layers' link but no 'wmts' (not sure if that helps).  Any way not asking a question just commenting that the issue may lie at the server end rather than client.

Comment: Finally, I have got the solution. I have forced KVP to work into ArcMap. Now, I am able to access the WMTS layer into all software(ArcMap, QGIS, Global Mapper, and MapInfo).

Comment: can you add an answer about how you forced KVP in ArcMap to help others with this issue